# Firebase project works locally but deployed version outputs CORS error

Tags: firebase, cors, preflight

I have a firebase project with hosting for the frontend and a cloud function to handle all the backend requests. When I do firebase serve, and run the project on localhost, everything is fine. But, after deployment, when I try to access it online I get the following error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I have tried all the solutions for enabling CORS in firebase, but the error just doesn't disappear. What is causing this error and what can I do?

**Relevant code in app.js (index.js equivalent) for cloud function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var express = require('express');
var cors = require("cors");

// These contain all the POSTS for the backend
var routes = require('./server/routes/routes');
var api = require('./server/routes/api');

var app = express();

app.use('/routes', routes);
app.use('/api', api);
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

exports.app = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest(app);
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public/client/dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
      },
      {
        "source": "/routes/**",
        "function": "app"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source":
          "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp|js|css|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=604800"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) allows AJAX requests to skip the Same-origin policy and access resources from remote hosts.

```
The * wildcard allows access from any origin
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));

If you want to restrict AJAX access to a single origin, you can use the origin
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}));
```

To enable HTTP cookies over CORS

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: '*'
}));

OR

app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}));
```